# Is it common to set objects to nil?

Tags: ruby

I am building an app and wonder if setting an unused object to
nil is a common practice in production level coding.

I understand that it is a mere hint for the garbage collector and won't always dispose of an object.

Comment: It's my guess that it should help, but in most cases you shouldn't need too.

Comment: The only time I set a variable to nil is when I have a junk variable that needs to start from a known setting, and, even then, it's been very seldom I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything to give the garbage collector any hints.  Just use an algorithm that is memory efficient enough, and it'll take care of the rest for you.

Answer (score 9):

According to this [thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4368466)

If you are done using a member object setting it to `nil` will provoke the referenced object to be garbage collected. If it is a local variable the method exit will do the same thing.

That said I would question your design if you require a member to be explicitly set to `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not common practice. There are only rare cases, where you explicitly set object to nil.

For example, in the implementation of some data structures it makes sense to set objects to nil. Let's say you implement a cache and you provide an method to delete a key. Let us further assume that the cache internally uses an array that holds references to the deleted object. Then it is recommended to delete all references to the deleted object by setting them to nil.

However, in practice, these situations do not occur very often.