# Memory leak in ruby

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, irb

I have such code in irb:

```
2.6.3 :001 > a = []; 100000000000.times do a.push([1]) end
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
        3: from (irb):1
        2: from (irb):1:in `times'
        1: from (irb):1:in `block in irb_binding'
IRB::Abort (abort then interrupt!)
2.6.3 :002 > a.clear
 => [] 
2.6.3 :003 > GC.start
 => nil 
2.6.3 :004 > a.size
 => 0 
2.6.3 :005 > exit
```

My memory chart:

[image]

So memory is completely released only at the exit.

How memory can freed completely before app exit?

Comment: Leak? I'd recommend reading http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idm368.

Comment: I edit question. "How memory can freed completely before app exit?" - added

Comment: The process will release all of its memory when it terminates. Anything left-over is an artifact of how your OS works or JVM if this is JRuby.

Comment: You don't need to tell us if you changed something. We can tell by looking at the revision data.

Comment: I don't think this is an OS issue. Ruby memory management is complicated, and it tends to not want to free allocated space in all situations, even if the object space is cleared.

Comment: This book gives some clues: https://books.google.fi/books?id=Vg9QDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT226&lpg=PT226&dq=how+to+get+ruby+to+free+array+space&source=bl&ots=QmM0k6t8lN&sig=ACfU3U09IT7r3oM7XUzm6IumIY7G5sX4gw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVsIGJj9roAhVQpYsKHRg8C8wQ6AEwAHoECA0QKQ#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20get%20ruby%20to%20free%20array%20space&f=false

Comment: More study material for OP: https://thorstenball.com/blog/2014/03/12/watching-understanding-ruby-2.1-garbage-collector/

Comment: I try jruby-9.2.11.1 - same behavior

Comment: I don't understand this question. Where are the [tag:memory-leaks]?

Comment: I also try mruby - same behavior

Comment: I have memory leak because need to operate with arrays for much time (about 5 hours and more). So I can not use  array = nil or array.clear. I spent all my server memory

Comment: Even more study material: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38659027/3784008

Comment: Seems I need learn new program language after 10 years :)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rYdYwxLJ - also seems it is classic problem from 2016

Comment: Also it seems you’re doing everything except reading the resources provided to you in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Operating as Designed

It's a leak if and only if the memory isn't returned to the system after Ruby exits. Since that's not the behavior you're describing, it's fair to say that your interpreter appears to be operating as designed.

See below for a little more about how Ruby's garbage collection works at a high level, and why your array-building is so memory intensive.

### No Memory is Leaking

This is not a leak; this is how Ruby [garbage collection](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/GC.html) works! It's basically a mark-and-sweep garbage collector, with some new support for compaction. At a high level, Ruby allocates memory for objects still in scope, and generally won't release the allocation until all references go out of scope.

Ruby's garbage collection isn't well-documented outside of source code, and the implementation is a bit more complex than what I described above. Furthermore, the garbage collection implementation can vary from release to release, and between different interpreters (e.g. JRuby and MRI) too! Still, it's sufficient to understand what you're seeing.

Basically, `100000000000.times do a.push([1]) end` will push an element onto Array *a* 100 million times. As long as *a* is in scope, the memory won't be garbage collected. Even if you manually start the garbage collector routines after *a* goes out of scope, Ruby may or may not free the memory if the system isn't under memory pressure.

I wouldn't worry about this unless you have very long-lived processes that need to keep millions of records in active memory. If you do, a purpose-built cache or database (e.g. memcached, Redis) might be more efficient.